# How to change style of div #id that contain selected .class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change style of div `#info_frame` that contain class `nazwa_klasy_display` and I can't fix it.

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function() {       
   //show up scores
   $( this ).children( '.scores' ).css( 'display', 'block' );

   nazwa_klasy = $( this ).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

   nazwa_klasy_display = nazwa_klasy.split('_')[1];
   if ($('#info_frame').has(nazwa_klasy_display)) 
   {
      $('#info_frame .'+nazwa_klasy_display).style.display ="block";    
   }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#info_frame .'+nazwa_klasy_display).css('display', 'block');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're mixing jQuery with plain Js:

either you use

```
/* chain a jQuery method, e.g. show()  */
$('#info_frame.'+nazwa_klasy_display).show()
```

or

```
/* access to the dom node before using plain js */
$('#info_frame.'+nazwa_klasy_display).get(0).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: What do you think about `$('#info_frame .'+nazwa_klasy_display)[0]`?

Comment: better shortcut for get(0) but applied to just one element the performance gain won't be really noticeable. it was just to show the access to the dom node

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you are looking for a `<div>` that has the id of `info_frame` and the class of `nazwa_klasy_display` then you do need to fix your CSS selector. you have a space in there when it shouldn't be.

```
$('#info_frame.'+nazwa_klasy_display)
```

the selector `#info_frame .[nazwa_klasy_display]` will be looking for anything that has the class `nazwa_klasy_display` that is a descendant of `*#info_frame`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#info_frame").hasClass('.'+nazwa_klasy_display).css('display','block');
```

try this